# How can I configure libcurl build base on curl-config?

Tags: curl, libcurl

As far as I know curl-config gives ionformation about a lib curl installation.
How can I configure lib curl with those params?
how to match the params recieved from the curl-config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl-config is a script generated at build time that has information about the curl build (and installation) use its command line flags to extract that info.

When you say "configure libcurl" I assume you mean running ./configure to build a fresh version from source? My advice is then to run ./configure and then see how its final "summary output" compares to your previous curl-config --features list or similar. Then adjust the configure command line accordingly and run again, until the summary table pleases you.

Comment: That's what I did, Thanks!